# I would like some help making a table that prints 1-100

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, computer-science

So here are my assignment requirements:

1. Print out all the numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive, 10 numbers per line evenly spaced out using tabs.
2. Use a max of 2 loops and 1 if statement.

I have a pretty good understanding of how this needs to be done but I'm just having trouble figuring out a way to start a new line after every 10 numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Table {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int counter, value;
        counter = 1;
        value = 0;
        while (value < 100) {
            value += counter;
            System.out.print(value + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the `Scanner` for?

Comment: Woops! When im working on projects for class I just copy and paste an old program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a new line, print the '\n' character.

```
if ((value % 10) == 0) {
    System.out.print("\n"); // Or really, just System.out.println();, since that makes a new line.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help :) I didn't think to use the % operator

Comment: @TheAventador also, if you feel that your question has been fully answered, please 'accept' the answer so others know it has been taken care of (click the green 'check' under the voting arrows). Otherwise, we are likely to continue bombarding you with answers. ;) (But if you want more perspectives, no worries leaving it open.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Work through each row in your table, and for each of these print each of the numbers x1, x2, x3, x4, ..., x + 10 followed by a newline character.
2. Work through all of the numbers individually, and after each one check to see if it's a round number of tens (think modulo arithmetic), and if is, follow it with a new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the span of numbers you need to iterate over, I'd use a for loop, starting at 0 and ending at < 100.

You're missing the increment, counter++ within your loop.

Use an if statement within the for loop, if (i % 10 = 0) {System.out.println(value + "/n";}, else System.out.println(value + " ");

Best of luck on your assignment.